# Can you stop Spring Cloud rebinding/reloading POJOs annotated with @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, configuration-files

If you annotate a POJO with `@ConfigurationProperties`, it allows you to easily load properties from a (`yml`) properties file and make them available at runtime.

However, when Spring Cloud is on the classpath, the behaviour changes somewhat: the POJO is now [re-bound](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes) whenever an `EnvironmentChangeEvent` is fired. That's great, unless you have manipulated the properties at app startup somewhat - those changes can now get overridden at any point.

Is there a way to stop that from happening (e.g. by adding another annotation to that class to say "never" rebind)?

In particular, I have a `@SpringBootTest`-annotated test class where a library I use is dynamically generating a port number. I'm accessing that number in my `@Before` method, and want to "inject" it into the POJO, so the app under test picks it up and connects to that port (i.e. the equivalent to `-Dmy.port=0000` at JVM launch). What would be a better way to achieve that (if switching off the rebinding and just assigning the value to the right field doesn't work or is the wrong approach)?

I have tried setting it via `System.setProperty()`, unsurprisingly with little success, or to add it via adding a new `PropertySource` to the `ApplicationContext`, and by using the `TestPropertySourceUtil.addInlinePropertiesToEnvironment()` - all to no avail...